# How to get cpu usage % in C# for each running process

Tags: c#, process, system.diagnostics, processlist

I use System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses() to get process list.
I found TotalProcessorTime property for each process - it is TimeSpan.

But how to get relative values of CPU usage, i. e. i need % of total CPU usage for each running process.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278071/how-to-get-the-cpu-usage-in-c

Comment: Also read Hans' answer to understand what CPU percentage actually means: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134199/processor-usage/4135301#4135301

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround decision see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396471/is-there-any-c-framework-or-code-to-parse-blg-perfomance-counter-log-files)

The plan is as follows: take counters data in stndard way, then process log files.
Realtime monitoring is not critical.

Answer (score 1):

use WQL (queries WMI like SQL)
see attached link for few samples:[WQL](http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/10/wmi-made-easy-for-c/)

**Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process** is your class for getting CPU data.