# Is there any way to get first line (header) and last line of blg file similar like csv file

Tags: c#, performancecounter

I am able to get first line (header) and last line of `CSV` file using below code,

```
string lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Files\test.csv");
string firstLine = lines.First();
string lastLine = lines.Last();
string result = firstLine + "\r\n" + lastLine;
File.WriteAlltext(@"C:\Files\test_Copy.csv", result);
```

Now I have a same requirement for `performance counter (blg)` file, but looks like `File Readline` is not working for `blg` file.

```
string line1 = File.ReadLines(@"C:\Files\BasicPerfCounters.blg").First();
```

The above code for reading first line of `blg` won't throw any exception, but output is `not` plain text,

[image]

Whereas, the first line read of `csv` output is plain text,

[image]

**Note -** One thing I can do that I can convert `blg` file to `csv` file using `Relog.exe` (https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2008/05/20/two-minute-drill-relog-exe/) and then I can easily read first line (header).

Is there any way to get first line (header) of `blg` file without convert it to `csv`?

Here is sample `blg` file, https://github.com/Microsoft/Tx/blob/master/Traces/BasicPerfCounters.blg

Comment: ReadAllLines will save all lines and you only need two.  ReadLine and only save first and last would be more efficient.

Comment: thanks for info, but my concern is different

Comment: "it does not work" won't help anybody. What is the behavior you're seeing? Does it throw an exception? Does it return a single line? Nothing?

Comment: @Kevin, I updated the output for both `blg` and `csv` first line output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any C# framework or code to parse \*blg Perfomance Counter log files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396471/is-there-any-c-sharp-framework-or-code-to-parse-blg-perfomance-counter-log-file)

Comment: @Paparazzi, I know I can convert `blg` to `csv` and then proceed. Is there any way without converting?

Comment: I can read what you are asking and in my mind it is a duplicate.  If I had an answer then I would answer the duplicate.

Comment: Ok, no problem, Thanks!